# Is there any way to find the rows of a list that meet a certain condition in R?

Tags: html, r, rvest

In R, I am **scraping** data from a website.

After performing the scrape, I end up with a xml_nodeset type object. Each of those rows has an href character tag assigned. I would like to extract the rows of the list whose href tags meet a certain conditions.  Any ideas on how to do it?

Right now, I am stuck with the xml_nodeset object, as I do not know how to move on.

Thank you!

```
page <- read_html("elopage.html")
country_name <- page %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="mainContent"]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/table')  %>%
  html_nodes("a")
```

Comment: Please provide a reprex look into dput

Comment: FYI it's __scraping__ not scrapping